# Switch between Single and Dual-Monitor output

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, macbook

is there a way to **switch between single and dual monitor view** on my macbook pro running mac os x leopard? Maybe a shortcut or something?

To be more detailed:
I'm running mac os x on a laptop. Sometimes I connect an external monitor to my mac and I want to switch on the fly between:

- dual monitor view
- single monitor view (either laptop
  monitor or external monitor is
  activated)

Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go under "Displays" in System Preferences and check (click on) the "Mirror Displays" box to mirror the displays and then turn off (lower brightness on your laptop or turn off your external) the monitor you aren't using.